# I want to create India map with counts of state using Python and it's Data visualization library. and have it on a website

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, data-visualization, data-analysis

I first connected to my local Postgre sql. And then created a pandas dataframe

The dataframe looks like-

```
    State             Clear     Suspect
0   UTTAR PRADESH     4540278   863091
1   RAJASTHAN         1866196   373572
2   MADHYA PRADESH    1373106   311683
3   WEST BENGAL       1367113   294851
4   KARNATAKA         1012743   243519
```

The script for Database connection looks like -

```
# This gist contains a direct connection to a local PostgreSQL database
# called "suppliers" where the username and password parameters are "postgres"

# This code is adapted from the tutorial hosted below:
# http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-python/connect/

import psycopg2

# Establish a connection to the database by creating a cursor object
# The PostgreSQL server must be accessed through the PostgreSQL APP or Terminal Shell

# conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=suppliers port=5432 user=postgres password=postgres")

# Or:
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", port = 5432, database="postgres", user="postgres", password="123")

# Create a cursor object
cur = conn.cursor()

# A sample query of all data from the "vendors" table in the "suppliers" database
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM data""")
query_results = cur.fetchall()
print(query_results)

# Close the cursor and connection to so the server can allocate
# bandwidth to other requests
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I want to show clear and suspect counts on India map for each state using any python visualization library.
The main aim is to have 'Clear' and 'Suspect' count for each state on hover.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can have a look at folium or plotly.

Comment: folium doesn't provide updated map of India.